# c++ : invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: c++

I don't know what's wrong here ?
It's just running errors !!!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << string("hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A C++ program consists of *keywords* and *identifiers*. Learn what the keywords are. You can use keywords freely, but you must not use *any* identifier unless you have proven to yourself that that identifier has been declared in your program.

Comment: what is string? You don't have anything defining it.

Comment: you probably forgot `#include <string>`

Comment: @Michael Chen  Though some compilers include the header <string> into the header <iostream> nevertheless you should explicitly include headers where the types you are using are declared.

Comment: thanks for your advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read more about C++. So read first [Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/).

Then read [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) documentation, notably the one about [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string)-s.

You need to `#include <string>`

You should enable all warnings when compiling. If using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), compile with `g++ -Wall -g`

Comment: It seems, you forgot to include the Bible.

Comment: Well, Stroustrup book is not bad, as an introduction to C++

Comment: Not all will agree with you.

Comment: thanks a lot guys
I've just started to learn C+＋ with C++ Primer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that `string` before the actual string:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

Or, alternatively, if you're trying to store a string:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "hello world";
    cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```